# Convert Expression to Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have a method that builds an expression tree, based on the Type of the object that is passed to the method. Once the tree is built, I want to convert it and return it with the return type as is shown below.

```
public static Expression<Func<object, bool>> BuildExpression(Type type, ...)
{
    // build the expression...
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type, "m");
    Expression expression = null;

    // simplified version of building the expression tree
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Property);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
    expression = Expression.Equal(member, constant);

   // ...

   // IT FAILS ON THIS LINE!!!
   return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(expression, param);
}
```

I've looked at a few conversion answers, but to no avail. Any advice?

Comment: Can you show a sample usage of this function?

Comment: What should the expression do when given a wrong type? Throw exception? Return `false`? Something else?

Comment: You need to cooperate if you want help. In general `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>` cannot be treated as `Expression<Func<object, bool>>` for the same reason that `List<Foo>` cannot be treated as `List<object>`. Provide the real use case in order to get the correct solution.

Comment: As Ivan pointed out. You should use `Expression.Convert(param, type)` before passing param to member expression. And also parameter should be defined as object - `Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "m")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with modifications as described in my previous comment.

1) Your function returns expression that describes function with single argument. And this argument is of type `Object`. So you should use `Object` type when creating parameter "m" expression.

2) Before accessing the property parameter should be cast back to desired type. See `Expression.Convert`.

```
public static Expression<Func<object, bool>> BuildExpression(Type type, ...)
{
    // build the expression...
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "m");
    Expression expression = null;

    UnaryExpression convert = Expression.Convert(param, type);

    // simplified version of building the expression tree
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(convert, filter.Property);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
    expression = Expression.Equal(member, constant);

    // ...

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(expression, param);
}
```